# Document Generator for library iphone

Tags: iphone, documentation

I have created one library, and now I want to have its documentation, so Is there any document generator available? If yes, What I have to keep in mind while generating documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.doxygen.nl/

Doxygen is probably the most widely used option. Because it's not just for ObjC (doxygen supports many other languages), the development is lively and the community quite strong. [HeaderDoc](http://developer..com/opensource/tools/headerdoc.html) (now an open source project), by comparison appears to have largely stagnated. HeaderDoc only produces HTML output, while doxygen also produces PDF, LaTeX and many other output forms besides HTML. Even  seems to recommend doxygen, with [this](http://developer..com/tools/creatingdocsetswithdoxygen.html) guide to automatically producing documentation sets, compatible with 's help viewer, from within your  build process.

It's worth noting that doxygen can read HeaderDoc-style comments, so you can write your documentation in HeaderDoc style and decide later whether to produce the final output using doxygen or HeaderDoc.